# The executable file is not being created when trying to compile a project made using a Multi Application Device in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create an app using Delphi 10.3. I've installed everything I need to (the SDK etc...). However, when I try to compile the project, the error message "Cannot open file "C:\Users\liamt\OneDrive\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\EXEC". The system cannot find the file specified."

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Are you really storing/compiling your projects on a *remote* drive? Why not on the *local* machine?

Comment: Compiling to OneDrive is probably not going to work. Also, this could be an issue with your antivirus software.